# Applescript Editor won't run program - syntax error?

Tags: applescript

Here's my script:

```
on idle

   tell application "Finder" to open the startup disk

return 100

end idle
```

When I hit compile, it appears to compile. When I hit run, nothing happens. I've made several variants and I get get any to run.

Answer (score 3):

It won’t run from AppleScript Editor, because AppleScript Editor doesn’t idle, so to speak.

One solution, if you need to run it from AppleScript Editor for testing, is to put the meat of the script into a separate handler, and then call that handler from both the `idle` and `run` handlers;

```
on openStartup()
    tell application "Finder" to open the startup disk
end doMeat

on idle
    openStartup()
    return 100
end idle

on run
    openStartup()
end run
```

If you don’t need to run it from AppleScript Editor, then just save it as an application. Applications get idle messages, and so it will work from there.

If you need to test multiple iterations of the script in AppleScript Editor, you can fake the idle by just calling the handler twice in your `run` handler, with a delay between them:

```
on run
    openStartup()
    delay 100
    openStartup()
end run
```

And of course you could also use a loop to repeat multiple times.

Just remember to comment out the test `run` handler when you save it as an application.

For simple scripts, I often just replace `idle` with `run` when I’m testing it, then put `run` back to `idle` when I save it.